What is the best way to drive an isolated high-side MOSFET as a switch, at high bus voltages?
I'm trying to drive an isolated PMOS as a load switch, connected on the high side to a DC bus voltage of 350V. My load requirement is 0-8A varying, but there is bulk capacitance before the load. So far, I haven't found any solution that would let me drive the switch "fast" enough that it doesn't spend much time in its linear region when the bulk capacitor is charging. I haven't been able to find gate driver ICs that drive MOSFETs as load switches, at these voltages.
So far I have tried the simple resistor-divider driven by a solid state relay. In this case, considering the 10k resistor, the time taken to charge the gate capacitance of the MOSFET Q2 would be (roughly calculated) 115us. Simplified circuit-

Some info:

The PMOS is not switched/PWM-ed. It is turned on, used for many hours, then VBAT is shut down after usage. The only time the PMOS will need to turn off quickly is during an overcurrent event.

I'm currently using IXTX40P50P PMOS. The part of the circuit after the PMOS (my "load") consists of inrush limiting resistors, current sensor with OC fault that will turn off the PMOS, a TVS diode and a small surge capacitor.

I have used a gate slew circuit before as a way to limit the inrush, now I have a graveyard of ~10 MOSFETs so I ditched that idea. The current config is to let the ICLs handle the inrush when the MOSFET is fully on.

The PMOS is mounted to a heatsink, and dissipation is not a problem. Full load heat dissipation in IXTX40P50P at Vgs = -10V and Ids = 8A is about 15W, and my heatsink is rated to handle it with Trise = 25C

Why not NMOS? I am fully open to the idea, but my reluctance stems from using them on the high side which requires more components.

Just reduce the resistor? I can reduce R10k a bit to improve the turn-on time, that would be my last resort in this design.


Question:
What would be the best way to drive ("turn on") the MOSFET in this configuration?
What kind of gate driver would work in this scenario should I try to use one? I was not able to find any components to use at this voltage levels and directly interface with the MOSFET.
If I change it to NMOS, how do I drive an NMOS at the high-side?

Please show the load (including bulk capacitor) and don't fragment your schematic with unneeded node-name connections. They make no sense on a circuit like this and are a hinderance to following the circuit.

Does it need to be steadily on/off or is it always a PWM control? These two scenarios might call for different solutions

@tobalt It needs to be steadily on, it would only turn off in an overcurrent event

@Andyaka Understand, that was a screenshot from my actual schematic. I have edited it to a simplified circuit.

Would a part like VOM1271 help? https://www.vishay.com/docs/83469/vom1271.pdf

@WesleyLee I did come across this part, but it is not rated for the voltage level my circuit is using (350V). Regardless of that, I'd still have to use the resistor-divider method to drive a PMOS

What's your max switching speed?

The question really needs many more details. What is the exact mosfet you plan on using? How are you limiting capacitive inrush current? How do you protect the wiring and battery from a shorted load? How often do you switch the load? How many Joules of heat are you willing to dissipate during each switching event in the switch? What is the conduction loss heat power in W at maximum load? What is the parasitic inductance in this circuit? For an application like yours, the switch will be on a heatsink unless you use a vastly oversized and expensive mosfet. It's normal.

Thanks for the input. I have added some edits to the question, but to reiterate, my original question is how to turn on the MOSFET as fast as possible (and keep it turned on).
@winny no switching, just turn on

How fast do you need to turn it on? A numerical value is needed.

The VOM1271 doesnt have to be exposed to 350V, its isolated so you can reference it to whatever you want. (but that maybe doesnt deal with your other requirements, just throwing some ideas around)


I haven't found any solution that would let me drive the switch "fast" enough that it doesn't spend much time in its linear region when the bulk capacitor is charging.

Switching things fast into a capacitor will cause high inrush currents and is probably not the best idea. It causes EMI, thermally shocks the capacitor, etc. Recall that half of the energy used when charging the capacitor from a resistive source is always lost. If you do it very quickly, the losses occur quickly as well, and some of them will happen inside the capacitor, as the switch impedance gets low enough to be in the same ballpark as capacitor ESR. The fact that the switch will dissipate some heat when turning on slowly is a benefit really. It's better the switch does that than the capacitor. It's pretty expensive to heatsink a capacitor :)
If you want to be hard switching while driving a capacitive load, you'll need an inductor and current control with hysteresis. The inductor will be switched to keep the average current at say 9A. Once the capacitor is charged, the inductor will stay on. If the load current exceeds 9A, the inductor will begin to be switched again, maintaining the current without heating anything very much except the load that is a nice room heater at that point.

Thanks for the answer, but perhaps I was not clear in my question and my circuit is too simplified. The load capacitance will have inrush limiters in my circuit, and any load circuitry is irrelevant to my question. My concern is how to drive the MOSFET: I do not intend for it to dissipate any heat when it is switching, only when it has fully turned on.

How are you limiting the capacitor current then? Normally the load switch would be doing that by dissipating, or the load switch together with an inductor will limit the current. Presumably a load switch doesn't switch very often, so any heat dissipation during switching is minuscule compared to the conduction losses when turned on. Have you assembled this circuit? Why do you think that the mosfet spends "too long" in the linear region? Have you tried to measure carefully if that mosfet switches say in 50ns?

If I am not wrong, there is some inrush current limit device in the circuit. As other users, I do not fully understand what is issue turning on at that speed,if PWM is not used. Anyhow this configuration can be easily improved.
From data sheet, the MOSFET Qg=205 nC , Vgs=-10 V. In a very simplified model, you can estimate (C=Q/V) a capacitance of 20 nF for the gate driver. When SSR is activated, the gate will be charged until -15 V at 1.5 mA, when Vgs <= Vth (Vthmin= -2V, Vthmax=-4.5V), the MOSFET will turn on.
To speed up this charging, you can reduce resistors values, but will waste more energy. Other solution could be to make a capacitor divider, adding a capacitor in parallel with 220K resistor, the value  should be the inverse of resistors ratio. See difference in following circuits:

Because this a very rough estimation, and depends on the component gate, a 15 V zener should be connected to limit gate overvoltage. Also R6 can limit current peak when charging to about 500 mA, it depends on the SSR current output. Also, after turning off, the added capacitor will need some time to discharge, otherwise will not work (not speed improvement) in the following switching on.

Regarding using a N-MOSFET type, for continuously switched on, the voltage drop will be greater than Vth, unless you use a isolated power supply for the gate driver. Other solution could be a photovoltaic driver, but the available current output is low, so not fast switching is possible.

Thank you for the detailed answer, this is what I was looking for (different techniques for driving). In your last paragraph, what does "unless you use an isolated power supply for the gate driver" mean? If this is a method to drive NMOS, please elaborate!

@shysd: take a look at this link: https://tahmidmc.blogspot.com/2013/02/n-channel-mosfet-high-side-drive-when.html  The BAT1 shoud be a isolated power supply,
